# Get Nodes which are not in collect

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want those nodes whose names are not in the collection of `a_row + b_row`. For example: `a_row` is having `b,c` and after combining `b_row` with `a_row` now `b_row` is having `b,c,e` and `entity.name` is having `a,b,c,d`. So I want the output `a,d` in the form of Nodes not in the list form.

```
match (a)-[r:relations]->(b) with collect(distinct a.FirstName) as a_row
match (a)-[r:relations]->(b) with a_row + collect(distinct b.LastName) as b_row
match (n:entity) with b_row where n.name <> b_row return n
```

Thanks in advance, Let me know if further information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the the `<>` by [IN operator](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/operators/#syntax-using-in-to-check-if-a-number-is-in-a-list). This way:

```
match (a)-[r:relations]->(b) with collect(distinct a.FirstName) as a_row
match (a)-[r:relations]->(b) with a_row + collect(distinct b.LastName) as b_row
match (n:entity) where n.name NOT IN b_row return n
```

Answer (score 0):

First

```
match (a)-[r:relations]->(b) with collect(distinct a.FirstName) as a_row
match (a)-[r:relations]->(b) with a_row + collect(distinct b.LastName) as b_row
match (n:entity) with b_row where n.name <> b_row return n
```

is invalid because the last `with` drops n, and can be simplified to

```
MATCH (a)-[r:relations]->(b) 
WITH collect(distinct a.FirstName)+collect(distinct b.LastName) as b_row
MATCH (n:entity)
// b_row in now a list, so if n.name is a string, <> is always false
WHERE n.name NOT IN b_row 
RETURN n
```

Which I would simplify to

```
MATCH (a)-[r:relations]->(b) 
WITH collect(distinct a.FirstName)+collect(distinct b.LastName) as b_row
MATCH (n:entity)
RETURN n, b_row
```

First to verify that your query is picking up what you think it is before filtering.

Comment: Thanks @Tezra! Finally I am able to figure it out that what was my problem. I was collecting the result into the another collect so the  **not in** condition was not working.